# How to save current new buffer (opened with :new) to other location, outside of current working location?

Tags: save

How to save current new buffer (opened with `:new`) to other location, outside of `vim_data` (which is default vim working location)?

My default Vim working location in `vimrc` is set to `~/Desktop/vim_data`

Let's visualize the folder structure like this:

```
~/Desktop
 |- vim_data
 |  |- sub1                             
 |  |- sub2
 |- general data folder1
 |- general_data_folder2
```

Inside `vim_data` folder there are subfolders called: `sub1` & `sub2`
current `:pwd` is in `vim_data`.

I want to save my current new buffer to `general data folder1`. How to I do that?

To open a file in other location is easy, I can just type `:e ..` or `:Explore`, but to save I have tried the method does not work.

Comment: Why not just `:w /path/to/file.txt` ? Or on Windows `:w c:\path\to\file.txt`

Comment: yes, that works, but i have type and tap such a  long nested location.  since i am there in "sub1" , can't i use "..

Comment: If vim's CWD (current working dir) is vim_data then you should just be  able to do `:w ../general\ data\ folder1/filename`. Note that the spaces are escaped with backslashes. If you use Tab completion you shouldn't even have to enter any of that. Start with `:w ../g<Tab>` for example.

Comment: @BLayer thank you. that works.

Comment: Good to hear. I shouldn't leave an answer in the comments so I'll transfer it to a proper answer when I get a chance. Please check back so you can accept it and, if you'd like, upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, @andrew_ysk if you'd like to get a bit of rep you're welcome to turn the above into an answer. Let me know either way.

Comment: i don't really know what are the "games" in this forum.. hence i don't really understand what you said. when u said "rep" , i think u mean reputation ? what will happen if it is just left like this without a soln ?

Comment: Yes, reputation points. The "currency of the realm". It's a friendly offer in case you're interested. If you're not I will answer. It won't be left without a solution.

Comment: "Coin of the realm", I meant. :)

Answer (score 3):

if vim's CWD (current working dir) is `vim_data` then you should just be able to do

```
:w ../general\ data\ folder1/filename
```

### Note:

*that the spaces between `general data folder1` are escaped with backslashes.
*If you use Tab completion (`:w ../g<Tab>`) you shouldn't even have to enter any of that backslashes `\`.

- `:w ../`  dot dot here means "up one level" , same as in any os system. then type in the folder name that is located "outside" of CWD (of vim).

Comment: If you plan to keep working on more files in that directory, you can also use `:cd ../general\ data\ folder1` command from inside Vim, then after that just `:w filename` will do.

Comment: I usually go with `:saveas` so that Vim remembers the position and name the next time the file is sved

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt ':saveas' same as ':w' ? btw, how to make vim command as "code" like what you all made ?

Comment: `:saveas` is much like "Save as..." in most GUI apps. Whatever you specify becomes the new filename of the document you're editing (In Vim parlance it becomes the buffer's new filename). That doesn't happen with `:w`. BTW, I encourage you to get in the habit of using help as your primary source of info (`:h :saveas`, in this case). The answers are almost always there and you won't have to wait for someone's reply (_if_ they even do reply). And the way to make "code" is surround the text with back-tics (usually same key as tilde '~'...at least for U.S. keyboards).

Comment: @andrew_ysk the difference between `:w some_other_file` and `:saveas some_other_file` becomes apparent if you want to save again later. With `:w some_other_file` a following `:w` will write to the original file name, while after a `:saveas some_other_file` a following `:w` will continue to write as `some_other_file`.

Answer (score 0):

I have windows so: `:write .\filename.py` will save the open buffer to the root of where you open nvim.

For example if you opened nvim like this:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MyProject> nvim .
```

Then
saving the file like this will save it to the `MyProject` folder: `:write .\file.py`.